# Pivot Table column headers using less than

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Ive currently got a pivot table showing number of weeks various people work. Id like to create a cumulative table with column headers showing count of people working <2 weeks, <4 weeks, <6 weeks and so on.

Currently I can only get the column headers to show independent count so for instance 2 people worked 2 weeks, 1 person worked 4 weeks. Id like to show 2 people worked =<2 weeks, 3 people worked =< 4 weeks. Is this possible with a pivot?

Comment: I think this is not possible within the pivot table itself. As far as I know you will have to EITHER create a table in the cells around your pivot OR create some extra fields in your original table to get this working. Alternatively you could just recreate the pivot table with formula's or VBA script altogether and then any (sub)total or count is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get something similar to your requirements with running totals. I created a very simple set of data, two columns with name and number of weeks, to use as source for a pivot table. I then used Weeks as the Column Label, Name as the Row Label and Count of Name as the value. This initially gave me a value of one where a person had worked a certain number of weeks. I then changed the Field Settings for the value to show a Running Total in Weeks.

Hopefully the attached picture will make this clearer.

[image]